# CSS Text Color not changing

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to change the color of my text (Normal and Hover) but nothing seems to work. Tried !important but still not showing. Have tried looking at other answers but didn't work.
CSS & HTML Div Code (I have tried removing text-decoration none)

```css
#five {
  position    : fixed;
  top         : 10px;
  right       : 100px;
  font-family : monospace;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size   : 16px;
  color       : red!;
}

#five:hover {
  color       : black;
  text-shadow : 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<p id="five">
  <a href="UNKNOWN" target="_target" style="text-decoration: none;">
    TEST5
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: `text-decoration` is completely unrelated to the color of text FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to style the `a` tag, not the parent.

```css
#five a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

#five:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

This happens because the `<a>` tag applies its own color by default (which is a benefit in most cases, but in your case you have to manually change the color directly by using the `a` selector).

**Complete, fixed code:**

```css
#five {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 100px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#five:hover {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}


/* this what I added */

#five a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

#five:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="five">
  <a href="#" target="_target">TEST</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Didn't know that. But thank you this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's because you need to colour the a tag so you could add a class or id to the a tag and then change that.

Change the css to this:

```
.five {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 100px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red!;
}

.five:hover {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

And change the html to this:

```
<p id="five"><a class="five" href="UNKNOWN" target="_target" style="text-decoration: none;">TEST5</a></p>
```

Comment: There's no real reason to have an ID *and* a nested class or ID. You can just use a child selector paired with the ID that already exists.